# How to allow access to a sub-folder and its contents, but not its parent folder and contents?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get my head around .htaccess rules and I am jumping in at the deep end with this one!

I have a site that is in the following layout on the server:

> www.domain.com/mysite

Now, I need to allow access to the following:

> www.domain.com/mysite/admin (and everything in the "admin" folder)

But, block access to:

> www.domain.com/mysite (and all the contents, apart from the matched
>   "admin" folder)

So far I have this:

> RedirectMatch ^/admin/?(.*) http://www.domain.com/mysite/admin/$1
>
> RedirectMatch ^/(?!admin)/?(.*) http://www.domain2.com/$1

But it doesn't seem to work?

Comment: I'm not sure but shouldn't you simply put the "restricting" htaccess in the parent folder, and then the "authorizing" htaccess in the subfolder(s) you wish to grant access to ?

Comment: I am using 1 htaccess file, in the folder "mysite". Do you mean I should use 2 seperate files?

Comment: I think so, but I'm no specialist. I think there is some kind of "cascade" of htaccess file : first the system looks in the specified directory, then in the parent, and so on, so you can be very accurate with security rules. Now I could be totally wrong, but that's a start...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/mysite/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite/

RewriteRule ^((?!admin(?:/|$)).*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [L,R]

(?!...) is the syntax for negative lookahead
(?:..) is the syntax for non-capturing group
(?!admin(?:/|$)) matches anything that is not starting from admin/ Or admin$
```

- Read more about it here: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Seems to work, excellent thank you! Do you know of any really good articles/tutorials/etc about htaccess? I just cant seem to get my head round it!

Comment: You're welcome. I just follow official manual: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html and rest is about learning regex

Comment: Just to add - would you might explaining the regex part briefly? I tried putting it into a regex tester and it was always matching the URL with"admin" in it, when it clearly lets it through

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Comment: Apologies, answer accepted :) Also, thank you for add some explaination!